# SQL - Query to select a row which text is smilar to my variable.(not "like " or "where")

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

I have a database table with questions. One column has the question text inside.

I want to make a Excel import. In the Excel file I have also the same questions as in the database. But I dont have similiar IDs to assign the right questions. So I need to find the right question with the text field.

My target is, to save the answers to the questions (which I read out of the excel) in a database table with the right question ID.

I am using CodeIgniter and PHPExcel to get the text out of the cell

So this is my model:

```
 function get_question_id($xxx, $quality){
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from("pa_it_question");
        $this->db->where('inttype', $xxx);
        $this->db->like('quality', $quality, 'before');


        if($query = $this->db->get()) {
                if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                        return $query->row('id');
                } else {
                        return $query->row('id');
                }
        } else {
                return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

And this is my controller:

```
 $quality = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cellQ)->getValue();
 $questionId=$this->MInterview->get_question_id($xxx,$quality);
```

The problem is that in my database I have html tags in the text. And because of that the queries "like" and "where" dont work.

I need a solution where I check the accordance or something like this.

Comment: I don't know what your html tags are in the db, but you could put them in separate fields from your text (like a "html_tags" field) and add them back as you generate a view (or whatever). Or you could add another field to your table with just the text and not tags and match against that (but then you'd have to make sure the text always matched in both fields).

Answer (score 0):

please refer to below this might help:

```
WHERE inttype LIKE '%your question to search%' AND inttype NOT LIKE '%the html tag you want to exclude%'
```